# Помогите найти модуль, компонент или плагин для Joomla.

Tags: joomla, компоненты, плагин

Существует ли какое-либо приложения для CMS Joomla осуществляющее тестирование пользователей? Если нет, то посоветуйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вариант решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно компоненты пишу сам если приходится... Приходится слава богу редко, зато работает так как нужно!

[Joomla component for create testing](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/living/education-a-culture/quiz) На их основе поищите на русском!